# Leibniz's rule's (one variable) proof

Tags: real-analysis

I' m having trouble with [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_Rule/One_Variable#Basis_for_the_Induction).

I'm stuck at this step (at the middle of the induction step):

$ \displaystyle \left({f \left({x}\right) g  \left({x}\right)}\right)^{\left({n + 1}\right)} $$=$  $\displaystyle \sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n \binom n k  f^{(k)} \left({x}\right) g^{(n+1-k)} \left({x}\right)
           + \sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n \binom n {k-1} f^{(k)} \left({x}\right) g^{(n+1-k)} \left({x}\right)
           + \binom n 0 f \left({x}\right) g^{(n+1)} \left({x}\right)
           + \binom n n f^{(n+1)} \left({x}\right) g \left({x}\right)$

I don't understand why at the change of variable the sum is only from 1 to n and not from 1 to n+1

Answer (score 0):

The original sums have $n+1$ elements. You are pealing off one term from each sum (and shifting the indices in one sum) to make them the new sums compatible. Therefore you are left with n elements in each sum, rather than $n+1$.